# DynamoDB Throttling

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamo table with 5 read and 5 write capacity. In this table I had two records.

I then decided to see what kind of error response I would get by pushing a large number of writes through at once (roughly 4000 records in one burst). The blue 'consumed' line shot straight over the red 'capacity' line however I got no error message of any kind.

The metrics show throttling taking place but my reads still occur and my writes still occur if I go over both capacity levels.

I have spent over 30 minutes pushing the read and writes well above capacity, with no error yet.

I'm not sure if this is because I am using the official javascript SDK in node js, which maybe transparently handles throttling and retries the throttled queries?

I'm hoping somebody can give me some guidance on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add a notice about throttling to the answer by @Luc Hendriks

Even after you are out of 'burst capacity' and DynamoDb starts throttling, you will get ProvisionedThroughputExceededException relatively rarely (as per my experience). This is because SDK silently retries throttled requests (so you were right, SDK transparently handles throttling).

You can use [maxRetries](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#maxRetries-property) parameter to disable automatic retries, so that you will get ProvisionedThroughputExceededException right after you see throttling in metrics.

Here is an example how to perform an update request without automatic retries:

```
var aws_dynamodb = new aws.DynamoDB({maxRetries: 0}),
    aws_dynamodb_doc = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({service: aws_dynamodb});

// ...
aws_dynamodb_doc.update(params, function(err, data) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. An odd 'thing' I am noticing is the 'returnConsumerCapacity' figure from the query itself. It shows 255 when I query a table for around 10,000 records but in the dynamodb metrics, it only shows 4.25 capacity consumed. Really puzzled by this!

Comment: How long does it take to query the 10,000 items? It is likely that the 4.25 is the average value over some amount of time, either 1 minute, or 5 minutes.

Comment: Yes, as it is stated in console, metrics graph displays consumed capacity units per second averaged over a 1 minute period. So if you have made a one query that consumed 255 units and during that particular minute you haven't made any other queries, then chart shows 255/60=4.25 per second

Answer (score 2):

This is because of burst capacity. You can read more about it on the AWS docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Bursting

Basically what it means is you can have up to 300 seconds worth of 'stored capacity' and use that as a pool when you have a spike in load. In your case that would be a pool of 1500 requests you can use instantly and is refilled again when capacity is unused.