# DynamoDB Throttling and retries

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681511/dynamodb-throttling) post got the closest to answering my basic question that was about the fact that I was pushing data faster than the WCU/RCU configuration for my table and was getting to see the requests throttled in the metrics but was not getting any *ProvisionedThroughputExceededException*. I now know why from the answers to that post. What I still do not understand is this:

If I have an item of size 50KB and my WCU for the table is 2 => 2KB, I am certainly going to be throttled. That means I receive a *ProvisionedThroughputExceededException* and the SDK silently retries. The question is what is the point of retrying as the next time, you are, again, going to try for the same 50KB write and going to see the same exception as the item is still 50KB and the WCU is still 2. If I do not revise my WCUs from the console, then the only possible window that can help me get this 50KB item through is the burst bucket of 300 secs which will amount to 600K, i.e.if I still have the bucket. Is my understanding right or are there other ways of getting this specific write of 50KB item, through, when the client retries?

Comment: the logic of size is not a client's responsibility, because the size limit may change tomorrow by AWS and client should not have to be updated. Hence client is not smart enough (for right reasons) to not do an early throttle.